# Can I enter the USA with an E-2 visa and a one way flight ticket?

Tags: visas, usa

Is it possible to travel the the USA on an E-2 visa with a one way flight ticket (no return), with the intention of purchasing the return flight at a later date within the allowed duration of stay? For example, within 1 year.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your 1-way ticket already the return part of a round trip where you already took the first flight earlier, or did you actually manage to find a 1-way ticket cheaper than a round trip ticket?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [USCIS explains](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/e-2-treaty-investors), your initial entry to the US in E-2 status is for two years, and you can extend it indefinitely. You are required to leave *eventually*, but you aren't required to have a return ticket at the time you enter.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You may have to convince the immigration officer that you will comply with the conditions of your admission in E-2 status, including having the means to purchase a ticket out of the country.  But in any event a round trip ticket is not required when you enter.